# How to use sendtohawkbit or Suricatta daemon to send feedback messeges to hawkbit?

Tags: swupdate, eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

This is yet another question relating to hawkbit and SWUpdate(Suricatta daemon):
Basically I used hawkbit and SWupdate to run a firmware update on the RPi on the target it says "Update successful, executing post update actions" and then asks me to restart. as far as I know the update was successful but on the Hawkbit GUI the rollout bar is still yellow and processing how do I use suricatta daemon or sendtohawkbit utility to tell hawkbit that the update was successful, also is it possible to get a live GUI where the rollout bar shows how much it has completed etc..

I am not sure exactly of the ActiodID parameter, how do I find that exactly.

[target_PC_rückmeldung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE48A.jpg)

[Hawkbit_rolloutbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5EUX.png)

Please if anyone could show me an example that would be nice, Thank you very much.

This question was asked on the Hawkbit Gitter as well.
https://gitter.im/eclipse/hawkbit?at=5a0bff5271ad3f8736e7baa2

Answer (score 0):

What parameters are you using? or are you using the configuration file for the hawkbit?

If you are starting your `swupdate` using parameters then put the `-c` parameters with your other parameters and it will return the status.

Example would be

```
swupdate -l 5 -u '-u http:yourhawbitaddress.com:port -t yourtenantname -i yourdeviceid -k yourtoken -c'
```